Why do I get unexpected computation results using std::pow?
I am running the following code to compute -1.9 * 10.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float x = -1.9;
    int value = x * (int) std::pow(10, 1);
    cout << value << endl;
    return 0;
}

The expected result should be -19, but I get -18 instead.
What is the reason and how can I fix it forever?
I have tried to convert float into int and also replace std::pow with other methods.
Both solve the problem, and why?

As can be seen in the linked dup, your calculation returns something like -18.999999999, which gets rounded down.

@KenY-N In this case, even though x is slightly smaller than -1.9, after multiplication with 10 it should be rounded to nearest by default before the truncation to int which gives again -19 exactly. It also can't be that std::pow(10, 1) gives something slightly smaller than 10, because then it would truncate to -17. In this case the problem is a bit more subtle. It can only occur for implementations where FLT_EVAL_METHOD is not 0.

@ZhonghanWang On what compiler/OS/architecture are you compiling and with what compiler options? This shouldn't normally happen if you compile e.g. for x86_64.

@user17732522 No, it shouldn't be rounded, and FLT_EVAL_METHOD has nothing to do with it. Why do you say "it should be rounded to nearest by default before the truncation"?

@KenY-N: Please do not promiscuously close floating-point questions as duplicates of that question. user17732522 is correct; the result in this case is not caused by floating-point arithmetic per se but is a consequence of evaluation methods in the C++ implementation as permitted by the C++ standard.

@KenY-N: Re “No, it shouldn't be rounded”: Yes, it should and must be rounded. Floating-point arithmetic delivers a result equivalent to the exact real-number-arithmetic result rounded to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format in a direction determined by the rounding method, commonly round-to-nearest, ties-to-even. Using the format commonly used for float, IEEE-754 binary32, float x = -1.9; gives x the value 1.89999997615814208984375. Multiplying this by 10 using float arithmetic would produce exactly −19, due to the necessary rounding…

… Further, we can deduce that std::pow(10, 1) produces at least 10, since, if it had produced a value under 10, (int) std::pow(10, 1) would have been 9, and x * 9 would have produced a value around −17.1, and the output would be “-17” instead of “-18”. Therefore, the C++ implementation did not evaluate x * (int) std::pow(10, 1) using solely float arithmetic. The C++ standard permits it to be evaluated with more precision than float nominally has. For example, a C++ implementation may use double for floating-point arithmetic even on float types…

… The C++ standard requires (by inheritance from C) the implementation to provide information about how it implements floating-point arithmetic in the FLT_EVAL_METHOD macro or variable. A value of zero would indicate the implementation uses the nominal type. We know this is not the case, which is why user17732522 says FLT_EVAL_METHOD is not zero. This question should be answered with information about how C++ implementations may evaluate floating-point questions, not as a duplicate of that other question.

Erratum: “1.89999997615814208984375” above should be “−1.89999997615814208984375”.

@user17732522: Re “This shouldn't normally happen if you compile e.g. for x86_64”: It is entirely possible for this to happen on x86_64; the compiler simply uses double for floating-point arithmetic instead of float even when the operands are float.

@EricPostpischil I am not aware of a x86_64 compiler that behaves like this by default. (Although there may be one.) That's all I meant.

@ZhonghanWang Are you just trying to learn how floating point works, or is the question you posted a simplified version of a problem you're having in a real program?  In any case, you should be aware of these things: (1) decimal fractions like 1.9 can usually not be represented exactly using the binary floating-point representation typically used by C++; (2) using pow() to compute powers of 10 to multiply or divide by can introduce extra inaccuracies and is therefore usually not a good idea; (3) when converting float to int, you almost always want to explicitly round, not truncate.

This happened because your C++ implementation used extra precision in evaluating floating-point arithmetic, which is permitted by the C++ standard. C++ 2020 draft N4849 7.1 [expr.pre] 6 says “The values of the floating-point operands and the results of floating-point expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.”
First, we observe that this would not have happened if your C++ implementation used solely float arithmetic. I presume you are using one of the common C++ implementations that uses IEEE-754 binary32 for float (and binary64 for double) with rounding-to-nearest, ties-to-even:

float x = 1.9; gives x the value −1.89999997615814208984375, this is the value representable in float that is closest to −1.9. (There is actually a rounding to double first and then to float, and the final result is −1.89999997615814208984375.)
Some implementations of pow produce results with slight errors even when the mathematical result is representable in the floating-point format. So we consider the possibility that std::pow(10, 1) returned a value slightly under 10. This cannot have happened because then (int) std::pow(10, 1) would produce 9, and x * 9 would produce a value near −17.1, and the output would have been “-17”, not “-18”.
So we know x * 10 was evaluated.  Using real-number arithmetic, x * 10 is exactly −18.9999997615814208984375. This is not representable in float, and the nearest representable value is −19.
Therefore, if float arithmetic had been used, the output would be “-19”. Since it is not, we conclude that float arithmetic was not used.

If double is used to evaluate the arithmetic, the output is “-18”:

x has the same value as above −1.89999997615814208984375. (While extra precision may be used in expressions, C++ requires assignments and casts to convert values to their nominal types.)
Multiply x by 10 using double precision produces −18.9999997615814208984375.
Assigning this to value implictly converts it to int, which truncates, producing −18.

You can check the method your C++ implementation uses to evaluate floating-point expressions by printing the value of FLT_EVAL_METHOD (which the C++ standard inherits from the C standard) using this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>


int main(void)
{
    std::cout << FLT_EVAL_METHOD << '\n';
}

0 would mean the implementation evaluates all operations using their nominal type, which we know is not the case for your C++ implementation.
1 would mean float and double are evaluated using double. (long double would use long double.)
2 would mean long double is used.
−1 would mean the implementation does not specify.

In case of GCC at least one should also be careful that the defaults are not conforming to the C and C++ standards. In particular GCC may retain excess precision of the -1.9 literal across the initialization of x and the use of x as operand in the arithmetic expression. That's not permitted by either standard, but GCC only has a mode conforming to C++ since GCC 13 requiring the -fexcess-precision=standard option or one of the -std=c++XX options. Otherwise this can have the effect of producing -19 although FLT_EVAL_METHOD is 2 (e.g. on 32bit x86), depending on optimization.
